# MSMQ transactional query exception handling

Tags: c#, msmq, servicebus

I'm trying out MSMQ with c#... I started by writing 2 simple console applications: one is the sender of a message (a class in a shared class library project) and one listener. worked great.

Next, what I wanted to learn is what happens in case of a failure on the receiving side (listener). So it got me started with transitional messaging. On a failure I see that the message stays in queue, but the server keeps asking for it. What I actually want to achieve is that the message is marked for X times retries at interval of times and then throw it to an error queue.

Now for my code...

**Sender**

```
Console.WriteLine("I am the sender");

Message newMessage;
MessageQueue queue = null;

string queueName = @".\Private$\MyQueue";

using (MessageQueueTransaction msgTx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
{
    queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
    queue.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable = true;

    while (Console.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        msgTx.Begin();
        Person person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Shlomi",
                LastName = "Or",
                Birthday = new DateTime(1982, 5, 6)
            };

        queue.Send(person, "person_label", msgTx);
        msgTx.Commit();
    }

    queue.Close();
}
```

**Listener**

```
Console.WriteLine("I am the reciever");
int counter = 0;

while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    Message newMessage;
    MessageQueue queue = null;

    string queueName = @".\Private$\MyQueue";

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
        try
        {
            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
                queue = MessageQueue.Create(queueName, true);
            else
                queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);

            if (queue.CanRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    newMessage = queue.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);

                    //newMessage.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
                    //Console.WriteLine(newMessage.Body.ToString());

                    newMessage.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Person), typeof(Object) });
                    Person person = (Person)newMessage.Body;

                    Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName);

                    throw new Exception("Some error");

                    scope.Complete();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception occured " + (++counter));
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            queue.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this code, what I see happening when I send only one message is that the error is thrown and it keeps trying to get the same message over and over. What I want is as explained above - some kind of retry and then move to error queue. how can I do that?